# How to use SqlDependency in WCF to notify WPF application

Tags: c#, wpf, wcf, sqldependency

Today I started learning about SqlDependency and all of it's features and I have slowly been testing it on my WCF Service. I've got everything working so far by following a couple of tutorials, but I got stuck at a very crucial point.

My issue is (and I know that I DO NOT understand the whole SqlDependency concept yet), that for the life of me cannot figure out how to send my client-side WPF application a callback from my WCF service after the `OnChange` event has been triggered. I might be wording everything wrong in my question, so please excuse me.

Here I **start** my SqlDependency:

```
    private string dependencyResult = "";

    public void StartListener()
    {
            SqlDependency.Stop(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["TruckDbWcf"].ConnectionString);
            SqlDependency.Start(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["TruckDbWcf"].ConnectionString);
            RegisterDependency();
    }
```

Here is my RegisterDependency method:

```
public void RegisterDependency()
{
    SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["TruckDbWcf"].ConnectionString);
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();
    command.Connection = connection;

    command.Connection.Open();
    command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    command.CommandText = "SELECT [Id], [Title] FROM [dbo].[Feeds];";
    command.Notification = null;

    SqlDependency dependency = new SqlDependency(command);
    dependency.OnChange += SqlDependencyOnChange;
    command.ExecuteReader();
    command.Connection.Close();
}
```

And my **OnChange** event:

```
private void SqlDependencyOnChange(object sender, SqlNotificationEventArgs eventArgs)
{
    SqlDependency dependency = sender as SqlDependency;
    dependency.OnChange -= SqlDependencyOnChange;

    StartListener();
}
```

I want to call my `StartListener()` method from my WPF app, so I use an

```
[OperationContract]
void StartListener();
```

And I call the method from my WPF application like so from a button click event:

```
service.StartListenerAsync();
```

So my question is: How would I be possible to get a notification/message/callback from my service to let me know that data in my `dbo.Feeds` table has changed? I have no clue how to do this and I feel a bit stupid that I cannot figure this out at the moment. Can someone please help me?

I want to show a message in a label in my WPF application that there has been a change in data.

Edit - I also have enabled the Service Broker and set the required permissions in my database.

Comment: Why do u not notify all clients with your business logic where your changes are prepared? Are other apps are also doing some changes to the DB?

Comment: Yes there will be another app that adds data to the table. And I do not fully understand your first question, but that is the plan that I want to notify all of the users that might be using the application.

Comment: My scenario wont work if other applications modify the database too. To notify your clients you have to implement this funcationality by yourself. But in this case u always need a bidirectional connection between service and client.

Comment: Since you already have the SqlDependency event firing, you need to create a duplex service to send notifications to your wpf client. This site has an example that can help you out: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/dhananjaycoder/a-simple-duplex-service-in-wcf/

Comment: @RicardoPontual Thx man I will go and have a look at it.

Comment: @CareTaker22 - Any update on this, were you able to figure it out, I am also stuck at the same place, even tried duplex service, thing is my StartListener method is getting called automatically after some time not on database change.
Thanks in advance